# Java Linux Daemons/Services with Server Side Input

Tags: java, linux, service, daemon, daemons

I have a java executable that runs a service. It allows the admin to input commands while the service is running. It usually requires an open terminal to run. I connect to my server via ssh.

I can launch the service and it works but I can't exit the terminal without the service closing.

I also can't create a simple daemon because then I won't have access to give the service server-side input.

**Is there any sort of daemon where I can have a terminal interface for input, or is there a persistent ssh terminal where even when I exit it will be left running?**

Answer (score 0):

to make your process do not close when you exit the terminal you can use command like:

```
nohup <command/run> >/path/to/log 2>/path/to/errlog &
```

If you want persistent terminal you can use command like `screen` or `tmux`